# What is the difference between dllimport, and w/o the indicator?

Tags: c++, dll

Assume class A is only defined in a header file of a dll library (no implementation in cpp) as following with two ways:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) A {...};

class A {...};
```

I try to use the library in my application, I find the first one doesn't work. Why? Any way to make it work with dllimport? Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to post a more complete example, and/or explain what "make it work" (or "what doesn't work") means.

Answer (score 0):

It's `__declspec(import)` with two underscores, not one.

Aside from that, if the library you're using was compiled with a different version of Visual Studio, it's likely that it won't find the symbols it's trying to import.

It should be assumed that libraries compiled with one version of Visual Studio will not be able to link with libraries compiled with another version of Visual Studio, due to potential ABI changes.

You'll need to compile the DLL using the same version of Visual Studio as the application trying to link with it.